# Configure VPN split tunneling for macOS based on selected apps

Tags: c++, macos, networking, vpn

My task is to develop split tunnelling feature for macOS so if I am connected to a VPN connection only selected apps can send their traffic to the VPN while other apps will be using local internet connection.

I noticed other VPN apps like expressvpn offering these features but I couldn't find any help over the internet how to achieve that.

Comment: Hello Mohammad. I believe you're looking for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Question is relevant to programming, the solution will be code based some sort of middle wear written in c++ I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution of this problem is [NKE](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/about/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001858-CH226-SW5), Apple's Network Kernel Extensions you can write your own kext which handles network operations on various levels.

I hope this clue will help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked this myself but [OpenVPN](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn) daemon exposes set of APIs which can be used to create multiple VPN tunnels for each application, as mentioned in your question.